# PHP adding country code for all currency formatting

Tags: php

I would like to have the country code display for all currencies when they are formatted. At the moment I have:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_GB', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $formatter->formatCurrency(-10, 'USD')  . PHP_EOL; //-$10.00
echo $formatter->formatCurrency(-10, 'CAD')  . PHP_EOL; //-CA$10.00
```

How can I make the USD currency display either -US$10,00 or -USD$10.00?

Thanks